# Как сделать, чтобы работали все кнопки, с помощью querySelectorAll и forEach?

Tags: javascript, dropdown

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы работали все выпадающие списки, а не только первый?
Насколько я понимаю, нужно перебрать все с помощью forEach, но у меня не получается.

И второй вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы выпадающий список скрыть не только при клике на кнопку, но и если кликаешь в любое место вне выпадающего списка?

```js
let drop = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
let dropBtn = document.querySelector('.dropdown .drop-btn');
let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
let dropBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .drop-btn');


dropBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  drop.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Tahoma";
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, span, div, p, a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown.active .drop-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.dropdown .drop-btn {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 32px 12px 20px;
  user-select: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../img/down-arrow.svg);
  background-size: 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 10px center;
}

.dropdown .drop-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
  top: 115%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown .drop-menu ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Исходник кода на codepen [здесь](https://codepen.io/dev_dev_dev/pen/xxEGGOw). Заранее всем большое спасибо!

Comment: повесьте обработчик на `body` и есть у `event.target` нужный класс (выпадающий список), то меняйте ему класс ну или в цикле на все элементы из `querySelectorAll` повесьте обработчики - но это уже как-то неэффективно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы назначить обработчики каждому выпадающему списку, мы получаем их коллекцию с помощью:

```js
let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
```

При существующей разметке и требуемой логике, больше ничего получать не требуется.

Далее комментарии в коде:

```js
// Получаем коллекцию списков
let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');

/* Перебираем списки */
drops.forEach(function(el) {
  /* Назначаем обработчик текущему списку */
  el.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    // Прерываем всплытие события, 
    // чтобы не срабатывал обработчик, 
    // который мы добавим к document или body
    ev.stopPropagation();
    // Переключаем класс у текущего списка
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});

/* Назначаем обработчик нажатия вне списков */
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  /* Перебираем все списки и удаляем у них класс active */
  drops.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('active', false));
});
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,ul,li,span,div,p,a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown.active .drop-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.dropdown .drop-btn {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 32px 12px 20px;
  user-select: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../img/down-arrow.svg);
  background-size: 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 10px center;
}

.dropdown .drop-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
  top: 115%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown .drop-menu ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Чтобы был только один открытый список:

```js
// Получаем коллекцию списков
let drops = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');

/* Перебираем списки */
drops.forEach(function(el) {
  /* Назначаем обработчик текущему списку */
  el.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    // Прерываем всплытие события, 
    // чтобы не срабатывал обработчик, 
    // который мы добавим к document или body
    ev.stopPropagation();
    /* Убираем класс active у всех списков, кроме текущего */
    drops.forEach(el => { if (el != this) { el.classList.remove('active') }; });
    // Переключаем класс у текущего списка
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});

/* Назначаем обработчик нажатия вне списков */
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  /* Перебираем все списки и удаляем у них класс active */
  drops.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('active', false));
});
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,ul,li,span,div,p,a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown.active .drop-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.dropdown .drop-btn {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 32px 12px 20px;
  user-select: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(../img/down-arrow.svg);
  background-size: 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 10px center;
}

.dropdown .drop-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 0;
  top: 115%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown .drop-menu ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="drop-btn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="drop-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за такой подробный ответ, теперь все понятно! А если мне необходимо, чтобы при клике на dropdown, второй dropdown закрывался, то как лучше это реализовать? Сейчас при клике на все dropdown, они остаются активные и раскрытые

Comment: @Oksana: всегда пожалуйста! По уточнению - т.е. чтобы всегда был один открытый список, либо ни одного? Желательно указывать это сразу в вопросе - быстрее бы ответ получили :)

Comment: @Oksana: дополнил.