# Скрыть открытый блок при клике вне этого блока

Tags: javascript

Вот код, при нажатии на кнопку, меню добавляется класс *active*:

```js
const btnmenu = document.querySelector(".btn-menu"),
    menulist = document.querySelector(".menu");

btnmenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menulist.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

Как теперь сделать так, чтобы при клике вне этого блока, скрыть его?

Знаю, что можно добавить ещё один блок оверлэем и, при клике на него, удалять класс Active. Но, есть ли более красивый способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте и замените следующее:

```js
btnmenu.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  menulist.classList.toggle("active");
});

document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menulist.classList.toggle("active", false);
});
```

Также можете посмотреть этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1211932/265406).